# Is there any practical purpose of placing read only memory (ROM) chip near a hard drive?

Tags: magnetics, shielding

**Premise**: a PCB file has ROM chips (I think they are masked ROMs?) placed beside standard 3.5" HDDs, which has lead me to a few questions.

- While the product is off, I understand that the magnets in the HDDs cannot alter the data in the ROM chips because ROM chips do not rely on magnetic charges to store data. While the product is on, I assume that the HDDs should generate magnetic flux. Can the voltage from magnetic flux (via Faraday's law?) alter (i.e. damage) ROM chips, especially over time?
- What is the rule of thumb about shielding (memory) components?
- Is there any engineering advantage of placing all storage components near each other besides the speed advantages?

Since the PCB file is from work, I will not post it here. The PCB designer has also left the company before I started and so I cannot ask them directly why the product was designed like this!

Comment: Usually the hard drives are encased in an aluminum shell. The flux won't be much since the first thing getting damaged, is the data on the disks themselves.

Comment: There is no reason other than it being practical for PCB routing reasons. The ROM and hard drive may not be related in a way that relates to magnetism.

Comment: `besides the speed advantage` ... does that advantage really exist?

Comment: While the flux is certainly strong *within* the voice-coil assembly and *near* the microscopic read-write heads, I'd imagine this would be mostly contained.  A ROM nearby shouldn't have any issue operating in an additional weak magnetic field - the Earth constantly exerts a weak magnetic field and ROMs are immune to that.  They are not immune to very strong fields, but that failure mode ultimately has to be intentional.  Even many speakers today use shielded magnets.

Comment: Note that mask ROM specifically is pretty resilient; there's not much you could do to it that would change the data on it. The worst you could do is kill the electronics involved in addressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons to include a ROM on a product, some of which include storing a serial number or other product information, storing permanent firmware.

> What is the rule of thumb about shielding (memory) components?

If it's making the device an unintentional radiator and making it not comply with FCC standards then that would be a reason to shield it.

> Is there any engineering advantage of placing all storage components
> near each other besides the speed advantages?

It might be easier to route, HDD'S usually have fairly small PCB's so it would be common for many components to be placed next to each other. Power routing may be easier. It really depends on the frequencies involved, usually placing components next to each other can facilitate shorter data traces and reduce capacitance.